# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Xmlconnect_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento-1.7

I am getting this error on my local magento.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Xmlconnect_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php on line 546.

Edit:

I have checked the file is there on the correct path. Also I have checked the file was not in include/src directory so copied the directory to this path also and compiled from command line,but getting the same error, Any idea how to fix it??

Comment: Have you disabled the cache? If yes, set `<disable_local_modules> `to `true` in `app/etc/local.xml`. Then check again. If the error is not appearing, then it means one of your custom module contains the issue. You can start from that point

Comment: It was enabled, but as I am unable to go to admin because of this error, unable to check it.

Comment: I have updated the local.xml. Now I have to clear cache but I am unable to go to the cache management page in admin panel. Also the cache directory is empty and getting the error.

Comment: delete the cache and session manually and  try

Comment: deleted, but noting happends

Comment: Do you have "compilation mode" enabled?

Comment: As @oleksii.svarychevskyi asked - if you have files in *`src`* then you are looking at an issue related to compiler.

Comment: i had the same error, the XmlConnect module is disabled in core Magento but a theme we have in place tried to use it for translations. 

<description-more translate="message" module="xmlconnect">

Comment: Check if xmlconnect module is set to false in /app/etc/modules/Mage_XmlConnect.xml